# Script to enumerate AD groups and members exhausting TCP ports

Tags: sockets, powershell, tcp

I have a script that I've been working on for some time that does a few things:

1. Use `Get-ChildItem2` (from the module listed below) to traverse a directory and store the paths. I need to use this version of `Get-ChildItem` because I have directories that are over 100k folders deep and without this I run into the NetBIOS character limit.
2. Use the NTFSSecurity module from here (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fieldcoding/2014/12/05/ntfssecurity-tutorial-1-getting-adding-and-removing-permissions/) to get a list of ACLS for those paths
3. For each group listed on the ACLs, go to AD and look them up and write it out in a master list of ACLs for that folder.
4. Go through the list of ACLs again, this time filter the groups so that im only left with unique groups, and then go to AD again and get the members of those groups.

This results in 2 separate TCP sockets for each item which eventually leads to port exhaustion. I guess I really don't know how this works at the OS level but I've never seen a separate socket for each call to AD - or more likely, I've never had to look because I've never done anything to make enough calls to exhaust the ports.

Is there anyway around this? If there is a better way, I'm open to it.

```bsh
$RootPath = Import-Csv "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\acl cleanup\Dir_List.csv"

foreach ($Record in $Rootpath) {
    # Build Output Files and headers
    $OutFile = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\acl cleanup\$($Record.name).csv"
    $Header = "Folder Path,Account,AccessRights,AppliesTo,Type,IsInherited"
    $Outfile2 = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\acl cleanup\$($Record.name)Members.csv"
    $Header2 = "GroupName,Member"

    Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile
    Add-Content -Value $Header2 -Path $Outfile2

    # Do a recursive Dir listing using the path from the input rootpath and
    # store it in FOLDERS variable
    $Folders = Get-ChildItem2 -Directory -Recurse -Path $Record.FullName

    # Initialize an empty array for storing the unique group names
    $groupnames = @() #initialize array

    # Main logic is here
    # 1. For each  folder in the folders listing,
    #    a) Get the ntfs permissions using the NTFS Access module and store it
    #       in ACLS variable
    # 2. For each ACL in each folder, write them to a master table of all ACLS
    #    before we move on
    # 3. Using the ACLS variable again, do a group lookup for that ACE if:
    #    1) it is a GROUP
    #    2) and not one of the builtin default groups
    #    3) and NOT in the Groupname variable already (ensures that I'm not
    #       going to AD for the same group over and over again)
    # 3. Now that I have the unique Group name, lookup the members using
    #    Get-ADGroup and pipe that to Get-ADGroupMember
    # 4. Write the output to a file
    foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
        $ACLs = Get-NTFSAccess $Folder.FullName

        foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
            $OutInfo = $ACL.FullName + "," + $ACL.Account + "," + $ACL.AccessRights + "," + $ACL.AppliesTo + "," + $ACL.Type + "," + $ACL.IsInherited
            Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
        }

        foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
            if ($ACL.AccountType -match 'group' -and $acl.Account.AccountName -notmatch '^builtin|^NT AUTHORITY\\|^Creator|^AD\\Domain') {
                $groupname = Get-ADGroup $ACL.Account.AccountName.Substring(3)
                if ($groupnames -notcontains $groupname.Name) {
                    $groupnames += $groupname.Name
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($group in $Groupnames) {
        $members = Get-ADGroup $group | Get-ADGroupMember

        foreach ($member in $members) {
            $OutInfo2 = $Group + "," + $member.SamAccountName
            Add-Content -Value $OutInfo2 -Path $OutFile2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have directories that are over 100k folders deep"* This is insane.

Comment: It is! Welcome to my world!

Comment: RichardX as @AnsgarWiechers said, this realy is insane, but can you check netstat or something to see if it is realy true that you are exhausting your ports, i find it kinda strange, hope to see some more information.

Comment: Frankly, I'd start by pulling the relevant portions of Active Directory either into an in-memory DataTable or HashTable or, if I ran out of memory, into an SQL database that I could query as much as I wanted.  Yes, if something changes in the middle of your process then something has changed in the middle of your process.  That's not avoidable.  Fetch everything from AD that you will need in as few queries as possible!  If you can make `Get-NTFSAccess` not resolve SIDs, more's the better!

Comment: You may also try increasing the number of available ports locally with `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=1500 num=63000`.  You can view what the current setting is with `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp`.  I'm not sure if you need to reboot for this setting change to take place.  That combined with adding a `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50` or similar might slow the script enough for existing TCP ports to time out.

Comment: I had wanted to post a copy of my netstat -a output to show everyone but its all dc names and IPs so that was out. Either way, yes, I was surprised to say the least that this was what was happening. I like the get everything out of AD into a file direction. Sounds like the way to go. Thanks every one for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
$groupname = Get-ADGroup $acl.Account.AccountName.Substring(3)
```

does a lookup for each group from each ACL on each folder of your 100k level deep¹ folder tree. Since there are only 65535 TCP ports in total of course they will be exhausted sooner rather than later.

Do not resolve the group names right away. Instead collect the (potential) groups in a list of unique names.

```
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    ...
    foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
        if ($ACL.AccountType -match ...) {
            $groupname = $ACL.Account.AccountName.Substring(3)
            if ($groupnames -notcontains $groupname) {
                $groupnames += $groupname
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do one lookup to retrieve all groups, filter the result by unique names, resolve the members of each group, and collect the result in custom objects that can easily be exported in CSV format:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter '*' | Where-Object {
    $groupnames -contains $_.Name
} | ForEach-Object {
    $groupname = $_.Name
    Get-ADGroupMember $groupname | ForEach-Object {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Group  = $groupname
            Member = $_.SamAccountName
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv $OutFile2 -NoType
```

---

¹ Seriously, this is nuts!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write something out! You are of course right so I got your bits working in mine and as far as I can tell in just a simple netstat -a while it was running, I can see the same number of ports being opened. So I guess the way this is all going is to reference or work against a copy of all the info I need in a file or a DB. Thanks everyone for the help - and I agree. It is nuts! This script is the bane of my existence!

Answer (score 2):

In the end, the port usage exhaustion was because of the NTFSAccess Module. I switched to using the built-in Get-Acl cmdlet and no more crazy port usage. I had to reformat some stuff and dig a bit deeper to get the properties I needed but it worked. One problem with Get-Acl, though, is that it doesn't return TYPE as part of the return from a folder so I couldn't initially filter out users. So I expanded on everyones idea of using a DB\file to query against and imported a full dump of groups using Get-Content. I then do a -contains against it and Bang! It works. Low memory usage, no port exhaustion, I'm only gong to AD to query membership of Unique groups and I can still use the Get-Childitem2 cmdlet to get around the Netbios character limit. As an aside because its funny - of the folders im scanning, I have one folder with 400k+ folders, 2 with 150k, and 4 with 30-60k.

Thanks again for the help!

Completed script:

```
#Import path list to scan and the Master list of groups from AD, excluding the base domain groups and Builtin
$RootPath = import-csv "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\acl cleanup\dept2_Dir_List.csv"
$MasterGroupList = Get-Content "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\acl cleanup\ADGroupOnlyDump.csv"

ForEach ($Record in $Rootpath){
    #Build Output Files and headers
    $OutFile = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\acl cleanup\dept2\$($Record.name).csv"
    $Header = "Folder Path,Account,AccessRights,AppliesTo,Type,IsInherited"
    $Outfile2 = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\acl cleanup\dept2\$($Record.name)Members.csv"
    $Header2 = "GroupName,Member"

    Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile
    Add-Content -Value $Header2 -Path $Outfile2 

    #Do a recursive Dir listing using the path from the input rootpath and store it on FOLDERS variable
    $Folders = get-childitem2 -directory -recurse -path $Record.FullName

    #Initialize an empty array for storing the group names so I can compare them and only store the unique ones
    $groupnames = @() 

    #Main logic is here
    #1. For each  folder in the folders listing,
    #a) Get the ntfs permissions using get-Acl and store it in ACLs variable
    #b) For each ACL on each folder, write them to a master table of all ACLS for the folder one at a time
    #c) When done, move on and do a group lookup for that ACE if:
    #   1) it is a GROUP
    #   2) and not one of the builtin default groups* - regex match not needed if imported group listing excludes them already
    #   3) and NOT in the Groupname variable already (ensures that im not going to AD for the same group over and over again)
    #2. Now that I have the unique Group name, lookup the members using get-adgroup and pipe that to get-adgroupmember
    #3. Write the output to a file
    Foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
    {
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | select -expandproperty access 

        Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
        {
        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.FileSystemRights
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
        }

        Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
        {
        If ($MasterGroupList -contains $Acl.IdentityReference.value.substring(3) )
            {
            $groupname = Get-adgroup $acl.identityreference.value.substring(3) 
            if ($groupnames -notcontains $groupname.Name) 
            {
            $groupnames += $groupname.Name 
            }   
            }
        }
     }
     Foreach ($group in $Groupnames) 
     {
     $members = get-adgroup $group | Get-ADGroupMember  

        Foreach ($member in $members)
        {
        $OutInfo2 = $Group + "," + $member.samaccountname
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo2 -Path $OutFile2
        }
     }
}
```